# Check if value within column exists, if not create the column

Tags: shell, oracle11g

I need to check if one of the columns in my db contains specific value. If it doesn't I want to create that row with folowing values:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
MODEL=$1

if true (SELECT * FROM table.STATISTICS
         WHERE MODEL = '$MODEL' )

do this (INSERT INTO table.STATISTICS('$MODEL',0,SYSDATE,0,SYSDATE,0); )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `merge` for this, run through SQL*Plus as a 'heredoc', so you don't have to do a separate count operation; the `merge` will do that for you effectively:

```
#!/bin/bash

MODEL=$1

sqlplus -s /nolog <<!EOF

connect user/pass

merge into statistics s
using (select '${MODEL}' as model, 0 as num1, sysdate as date1,
  0 as num2, sysdate as date2 from dual) t
on (s.model = t.model)
when not matched then
insert (s.model, s.num1, s.date1, s.num2, s.date2)
values (t.model, t.num1, t.date1, t.num2, t.date2);

!EOF
```

But using your real column names, obviously. It's better to list them explicitly even for a plain `insert`.

Answer (score 0):

```
get_count () {
    sqlplus -s username/pass <<!
    set heading off
    set feedback off
    set pages 0
    select count(model) from statistics
    where model='$MODEL';
!
}

count=$(get_count $1)

if [ "${count:-0}" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "its zero"

    sqlplus -S username/pass << EOF
    whenever sqlerror exit 1;
    set echo on
    set verify off
        INSERT INTO table.STATISTICS VALUES('$MODEL',0,SYSDATE,0,SYSDATE,0); 
    exit;
    EOF

fi
```

Comment: Using `-ge 0` here doesn't look right; that condition will always be true (even it was using the name consistently - should it be `count` or `model_count`?), so it would always do (or attempt) the insert. `count` will either be zero, greater than zero, or something odd like null (which you're treating as zero) or part of an error message. It won't ever be negative. So, you probably want to test for `-eq 0` there. And you're missing the `VALUES` keyword in your insert. I'm not sure if you posted this as a real answer, or if it should have been part of the question.

Comment: I made changes, but I went with your approach. thank you @AlexPoole